# Is the meta description filterable in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am filtering the page title in WordPress using `wp_title`. I now want to filter the meta description. Is there a filter hook available?

Comment: Look into `wp_head` default filters and actions, there may be something there, but more likely this is a theme-dependent question since adding a meta description tag is arguably totally useless from an SEO or markup standpoint beyond making your Google snippet more human readable.  So probably it depends on how the `head` is built in the theme or framework you're using rather than a default filter or action.  Look in `header.php` first obviously, after that it really depends on the theme structure where to look next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no official filter. Your theme could be using one however. Open up your theme's header.php and take a look. Keep in mind that your theme could be adding the meta tag using the wp_head action.

You can find out more here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress

Comment: Thanks for the info. I decided to create my own filter using apply_filters().